# General second order nilpotent 2x2 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I understand that this question has already been answered here :[All nilpotent $2\times 2$ matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200829/all-nilpotent-2-times-2-matrices/1200840#1200840).

However as I am unable to comment on posts, I am asking this question to address why it is the case that "All nilpotent $2 \times 2$ matrices are similar($A=P^{-1}JP$) to $J = \begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$", which is stated by the OP of the linked question. It seems to me that without first proving this the answer offered isn't a complete proof.

Answer (score 0):

It's the Jordan form of the matrix.

Basically since $A$ is nilpotent it's characteristic polynomial is $\chi_A(X)= X^2$ which splits over $\mathcal{R}$. Thus you can trigonalize A. 
If you know an eigenvector $u_1$ of $A$,  then you just need to find $u_2$ such that $ Au_2 = u_1$ and $(u_1,u_2)$ is a basis. Then in this new basis you'll have the wanted matrix.

Comment: I tried to apply your method to get the jordan matrix given but couldn't. Could you please show the steps how to arrive at the jordan matrix for 2x2 nilpotent matrices. It would help a lot.